# How to count number of rows and display that number?

Tags: php

Lets say for example there are 5 records shown on screen. I want the $questionnum to display the number 5, but it keeps stating that $questionnum is 0. How Can I get the number of the number of rows actually match with the number of rows which are outputted on screen. E.G if 5 rows then display number 5, if 3 rows display number 3 and etc.

Below is code:

```
 // Execute
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
      die("Error executing statement: $stmt->error"); 
    }

    $stmt->store_result();

    // This will hold the search results
    $searchResults = array();
    $searchOption = array();

    // Fetch the results into an array
    if (!$stmt->num_rows()) {
      $stmt->bind_result($dbQuestionContent,$dbOptionType); 
      while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $searchResults[] = $dbQuestionContent;
        $searchOption[] = $dbOptionType;
      }
    }

    if (isset($_GET['searchQuestion'])) {

      // If $terms is not empty we did a query
      if (!empty($terms)) {

          $questionnum = $stmt->num_rows;

        // If $searchResults is not empty we got results
        if (!empty($searchResults)) {
         echo"<p>Number of Questions Shown from the Search: <strong>$questionnum</strong></p>";
          echo "<table border='1' id='resulttbl'>
          foreach ($searchResults as $key=>$question) {
            echo '<tr class="questiontd"><td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>';
            echo '<td class="optiontypetd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchOption[$key]).'</td>';
    }
          echo "</table>";
    }
```

Comment: what do you use for `$stmt`? PDO? mysqli?

Comment: `num_rows` is a variable not a function in mysqli. `$questionnum = $stmt->num_rows`

Comment: please update your code to include how you select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already storing results in the array, just do

```
$questionnum = sizeof($searchOption);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$questionnum = $stmt->num_rows;
```

If it still empty, maybe because you forgot to call:

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

Read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) for more information.

Comment: If I include store_result(), it displays the correct number for number of rows, but now it actually doesn't output the rows themselves on screen. Can you look at updated code and see why?